# Write 4 : 'x&{.&.;: y' tacitly

Tags: j, pointfree, tacit-programming

Conor Hoekstra recently solved a Leetcode problem in APL https://youtu.be/QtvvQ7MdwKY The problem is to take the first `x` words from a character string `y`

In J, using `&.` (Under) and `;:` (Words) I can come up with a nice explicit one liner

```
solve =. 4 : 'x&{.&.;: y'         NB. Box words in y -> take first x-> unbox words in result while retaining spaces between
   s=. 'Hello how are you Contestant'
   4 solve s
Hello how are you
```

The trouble I am having is finding the tacit version that still includes `&.`, mainly because I believe `x` needs to be bound to `{.` during the creation of the verb.
This is also an example where the magic `13 :` conversion is not helpful

```
   13 : 'x&{.&.;: y'
4 : 'x&{.&.;: y'
```

I can solve it tacitly by using `;:^:_1` to create the inverse of `;:`

```
   solve2=. (;:^:_1)@:({. ;:)
   4 solve2 s
Hello how are you
```

But that is not nearly as pretty as the tacit version of `4 : 'x&{.&.;: y'` could be.
Anyone have a pretty tacit solution for `4 : 'x&{.&.;: y'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> mainly because I believe `x` needs to be bound to `{.` during the creation of the verb.

If creating a verb with an input is the key, shouldn't you use an adverb?

```
   solve =: 1 : 'm&{.&.;:'
   4 solve
4&{.&.;:
   (4 solve ,: 2 solve) 'Hello how are you Contestant'
Hello how are you
Hello how
```

`solve` itself isn't tacit (or a verb), but `4 solve` is tacit verb.

Comment: Yes, thank you Julian. I was not thinking of adverbs as a valid tacit solution. Great answer.

Comment: ...and  `_3  grab_words  'are you ready to go'` if you want to get words from  end  of string.

Answer (score 8):

With [semiduals](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/ampdot#Semiduals_x_u.26..28a:.60v.29_y_and_x_u.26..28v.60a:.29_y) (introduced with J902 or J903?) you can write `` 4 {.&.(a:`;:) s ``. Then `;:` gets only applied to the right argument, while still doing the inverse later. `` u&.(f`a:) `` would apply `f` only on the left argument.

Comment: Wow, I did not know this. Every time I turn around this language surprises me and I have been playing with it for 20 years! Off to play some more. Thank you xash

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write this as a tacit verb, but it's easy to do as a tacit adverb: `]:&{.&.;:`.

Comment: Yes, you are quite correct, although  at the time that the question was asked, tacit modifiers had not been reintroduced to the language.